# Is it known when the next Community Moderation election will be?

Tags: discussion, election

I missed the last election period and would like to make sure that I don't miss the next one, but when I looked at the last dates it had been on it was twice in February and once in July.

**Is it already roughly known when the next election period will be?**

Is it even a periodical process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it already roughly known when the next election period will be?

No

> Is it even a periodical process?

No

Moderator elections are not strictly periodic. They are held whenever the current moderator team cannot cope with the amount of work required to support the community.

Comment: For argument's sake: what if the current mod team is _unwilling_ to cope with the amount of work? (Note: I am aware of what's going on.)

Comment: @Frostfyre We have not heard, at least so far as I am aware, any plans from SE at this point on what to do about the exodus of moderators and those of us that are still inactive for moderation purposes. I would assume at some point they will have to do a phased set of elections across the network to make up for everyone that has left the site.

Answer (score 2):

All we know is a CM has stated [you won't see any elections this year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337941/warning-potential-new-moderators/340094#comment1124336_337941):

> "To the best of my knowledge there has been no attempt by SE to fill those missing volunteer positions." Just so you know, we don't run elections this late in the year due to holidays. The earliest possible we'd start running elections again is in January. - [animuson♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337941/warning-potential-new-moderators/340094#comment1124336_337941), Nov 11